# Get data from VARBINARY fields

Tags: 2010, sql, data

System: SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2012.

**Question** : how to get data from a content database field that are `tCompressedString(varbinary)` type? For example, table `[Content_DB].[dbo].[AllWebParts]` column `[tp_View]` data.

I know, that peaking in these databases are unsupported by Microsoft.. I am just curious.

I have tried few option, no success:

- `DECOMPRESS ( [value] )` is not working, because function is not support in SQL Server 2012
- `SELECT CAST( [value] AS VARCHAR(MAX))` is returning '¨©01'
- `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), [value], 0)` with variations of last parameter (tried from 0 till 4), returns same varbinary value or '¨©01'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying the database directly is not recommended or supported. See other methods for reading data, such as [pnp PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps). But binary data is just that: binary. It's not a varchar. A sql developer who adds a binary field to a table is doing so to store things like image files or other types of files in the table. This sort of content cannot be read by converting it to a character string.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But is there something, even outside SQL (like PowerShell or C# functions) that could bet data out of binary?

Comment: Out of binary? Perhaps check out this article which explains what varbinary is and what it's used for: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DataTypes/95761/